# How to match this using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying get get first table including html tags using preg_match ,but its not working 
here is what I am trying

```
 $con='<table class="first">
 <tr><td>31231</td></tr>
 <tr><td>25235</td></tr>
 </table>


<table class="second">
<tr><td>333</td></tr>
<tr><td>333</td></tr>
</table>';

preg_match('/<table class="first">[^~]+<\/table>/i',$con,$match);//It's also includes second table
preg_match('/<table class="first">[^~]+?<\/table>/i',$con,$match);//Not matching anything..
```

Please help ...
PS:I do not want to use DOM or other method ....only regular expressions.

Comment: `I do not want to use DOM or other method ....only regular expressions`- why?

Comment: I have used RegEx every where in my project .The purpose of this question is only to learn something more about RegEx.If I use other method here then I will face difficulties in future that's why I want to use regex.

Comment: have you checked? The second expression matches your first table.

Comment: @amit there's a lesson to be learnt here and it's not improving your regex skills: use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @bansi Actually To make my question simple and short I have modified it from my original code.I have tested my original code it's similar to that.

Answer (score 2):

Why the first expression is matching the second table as well is that `preg_match` is "greedy" by default. That means that if your looking for `<table>(.*)</table>` it will get everything between the first match of `<table>` until the last match of `</table>`. You can make it "ungreedy" by adding the **U** modifier.

```
preg_match('/<table class="first">[^~]+<\/table>/iU',$con,$match);
```

When using the "ungreedy" modifier, it will stop at the first match of `</table>`

There are several [pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
preg_match('/<table class="first">.+?<\/table>/is',$con,$match);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to cross the Alps, which of these would you use?

[image: Kitchen knife]
[image: Range Rover]

Regex is almost always the wrong tool for modifying HTML. It is a bad idea. You want to know how to use regex to modify HTML? The answer is: ***don't***. As in, forget it. Leave it. Go on holiday. You're a smart guy: *do something else*.

In this case, what you should do is to use DOM methods, as provided by a built-in PHP library *designed to do this task*.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$table = $xpath->query('//table[@class="first"]');
```

Comment: if I do not find a solution using regex then I will use your code.Thank you for this.

Comment: @amit I'm glad to help, but note that the real point of my answer is *use the right tool*.

Comment: Actually I have to deal with wrong html codes and missing end tags I can't use DOM there that's why I have chosen RegEx,but for this question DOM is a better option.

Comment: @Please match the first table of this code using your method.. ? http://pastebin.com/Q6SBsb83

Answer (score 0):

The second one is working,

```
$con='<table class="first">
 <tr><td>31231</td></tr>
 <tr><td>25235</td></tr>
 </table>


<table class="second">
<tr><td>333</td></tr>
<tr><td>333</td></tr>
</table>';

preg_match('/<table class="first">[^~]+?<\/table>/i',$con,$match2);
print_r($match2);
```

Tested on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Can you match the first table of this ? pastebin.com/Q6SBsb83